# Vue Js Web App Encounters error publish in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, vuejs3

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WEXr.png)

[Encounters error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZVW2.png)

i had encounters the above errors , not sure if those error are causing the page not showing anything

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grEw3.png)

vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
    transpileDependencies: true,
    devServer: {
        open: true, // auto open web browser
        port: 44366,
    }
})
```

Main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import router from "./router";

import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
import App from "./App.vue";
import VueCookies from "vue-cookies";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.use(VueAxios, axios);
app.use(VueCookies);
app.mount('#app');
```

i tried running my web app in IIS but there are errors , anyone have any idea to solve it ? , using visual studio 2022 debug , i am able to have the correct page and result

I wanted to build a Web application With vue js that i can publish into Azure Web App . i have only a simple page so far .

Comment: the error is specific to your build process and IIS environment, none of the code shown is really relevant.  it's sometimes a red herring that these MIME type error messages are actually 404s (not finding the files).  how did you build for production? how did you set up IIS to serve your files?

Comment: after npm run build , i published the project to a folder , and make it my ISS physical path

Comment: You can try to install fiddler and do a debug to see if your css file actually gets requested or not or are you receiving a 404 error .

Comment: there is something saying Vue js requires javascript to run , but my browser has enabled javascript

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.